# Cannot access wireless on my ACER Gateway NE56R laptop. However wired connection works perfectly fine

Tags: wireless, acer, intel-wireless

I am new to linux world. I am using ***Ubuntu 10.4*** I am using GATEWAY ACER NE56R laptop. And i *cannot connect my laptop to internet wirelessly*. Couldn't find any trail for a wireless connection either.
Can someone please help!!

Comment: The best driver for the NE56R is brcmsmac. Whatever you do, do not download bcmwl-kernel-source! brcmsmac is made into the kernel, so it should work on a fresh install if the installer didn't get bcmwl-kernel-source.

Answer (score 2):

It's always best to search by network card model rather than laptop model because the same model of laptop can contain a different network card depending on what they had in the factory on that day.

I suggest:

1. Open a terminal (Ubuntu 10.04 = applications - accessories - terminal) (Ubuntu 12.04 = windows key, type '`terminal`' - press enter)
2. Paste this: `lspci | grep Network`
3. Search Google for the model of wireless network card listed with 'ubuntu' appended.

Hope this helps.

Richard

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/19593-ubuntu-1204-wifi-not-working-at-laptop-or-notebook-unblock-it

**Ubuntu 12.04.  WiFi not working**

Check if the wifi card is blocked (Terminal)

`rfkill list wlan`     (for wifi)

OR

`rfkill list all`             (for wifi and bluetooth)

UNBLOCK:

`rfkill unblock wlan`     (for wifi)

OR

`rfkill unblock all`             (for wifi and bluetooth)

Restart the network:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```